# How to insert text between two set patterns with sed?

Tags: sed, scripting, regular-expression, html

I need to insert text between two set patterns in a large set of files.
I need to change every line with this form:

```
<a href="/entry/someFile">
```

To this:

```
<a href="/entry/someFile.xhtml">
```

I've been trying to write a `sed` command to accomplish this, but I'm finding it very difficult.

I know that I need to use `href="/entry/` and `">` as delimiters, but I don't understand how to use `sed` for more complicated text insertions/substitutions.

edit: I realize I was unclear in my original post. The unchanging patterns are `href="/entry/` and `">`. "someFile" could be any file name.

Comment: Is this in an XML file that is well formed?

Comment: No, its the product of a web page scrape that I'm turning into an ebook for personal use. I have to use .xhtml for the ePub editor Sigil.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>For a `sed` solution, see further down in this answer.</sub>

Assuming that the `a` nodes are part of a well formed XML document, and that you would want to append `.xhtml` to the value of their `href` tags when the existing values starts with `/entry/`:

```
xml ed -u '//a[starts-with(@href, "/entry/")]/@href' \
       -x 'concat(../@href,".xhtml")' file.xml >file-new.xml
```

This uses [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (sometimes installed as `xmlstarlet` instead of just `xml`) and it will find the relevant `a` nodes and append `.xhtml` to their `href` attributes regardless where in the document they occur.

The result is saved to  a new file here, but you may use `xml ed --inplace ...` to edit the file in place once you have made sure that it works.

Testing:

```
$ cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a href="/entry/someFile1"/>
  <a href="/entry/someFile2"/>
  <a href="/entry/someFile3"/>
</root>

$ xml ed -u '//a[starts-with(@href, "/entry/")]/@href' -x 'concat(../@href,".xhtml")' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a href="/entry/someFile1.xhtml"/>
  <a href="/entry/someFile2.xhtml"/>
  <a href="/entry/someFile3.xhtml"/>
</root>
```

---

Using `sed` (which you would *not* use on a well formed XML file usually):

```
sed 's|<a href="/entry/[^"]*|&.xhtml|g' file.xml
```

This matches the string `<a href="/entry/` followed by any number of characters that are not `"` (this would be the filename).  This whole matching part is then replace with itself and the string `.xhtml`.

With `sed -i`, this would make the modification in place.

Testing (on the same file as above):

```
$ sed 's|<a href="/entry/[^"]*|&.xthml|g' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a href="/entry/someFile1.xhtml"/>
  <a href="/entry/someFile2.xhtml"/>
  <a href="/entry/someFile3.xhtml"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

sed can be very complicate, but for your needs its easy to use try:

```
sed -i 's/<a href=".*">/<a href="/some/link/">/g' yourfile.html
```

The syntax here is easy:

```
sed -i 's/stringt before replacing/string after replacing/g'
```

the `.*` is the wildcard matches anything use it at the needed place

Maybe you should copy the file before using sed.
the `-i` changes your file not creates a new one:

> -i [SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX] edit files in place (makes backup if
>   SUFFIX supplied)

the `g` at the end replaces all matches in the file

if you want to change only the first match in your file use:

```
sed -i '0,/<a href=".*">/{s/<a href=".*">/<a href="/some/link/">/}' yourfile.html
```

same syntax:

```
sed -i '0,/string before/{s/string brefore/string after/}'
```

Comment: The issue with your first `sed` is that it would make a mess of a line that contains two sets of tags with attributes.